# Is this possible: 'I’ll never forget my country being invaded'?

Tags: vocabulary, gerunds

> forget (somebody) doing something ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forget))

What examples are there for the above construction? Can the case below be possible?

> I’ll never forget **my country being invaded** by the empire.

Comment: It's passable, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's excellent writing. I think an adverb might help improve it; e.g., _I'll never forget_ how _my country was invaded by the empire_ or _I'll never forget_ when _my country was invaded by the empire._ You could also use: _I'll never forget the empire's invasion of my country_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The example sentence sounds like the beginning of a "war story".  The story would tell what happened during the "invasion by the empire", and possibly tell what happened in the aftermath of the invasion.

For example, a Kuwaiti might tell you, "I'll never forget my country being invaded by Iraq."  You could then expect to hear stories about Iraqi looting, American bombing, and oil well fires.  The stories would be set in 1990 - 1991.

Answer (score 2):

If *somebody can do something to someone-or-something else* (usually known as 'active voice' in English grammar), then *something can be done to someone-or-something else* (by someone)" ('passive voice'). Here, we *could* say 'I'll never forget 'the enemy' (or say the name of that country) invading my country'. But the focus of your statement is 'my country', so you want to put that in the most important part of the sentence. You can even leave out 'by the enemy', because it is clear that countries are invaded by enemies. Or maybe it is important to include that information, which Jasper has done.